# how to maintain a count column in a database table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am here asking for your help because my encountering of a problem related to postgresql database, or any database software in general.

The situation is:

I have a table

```
    myTable(col1,col2,col3,count)
    #col1 is the primary key
    #count shows how many times row (col1,col2,col3) is inserted into the table
```

Take a example:

```
    col1  col2  col3  count
    1     hi    true  1 
    2     ok    true  2 
    3     no    false 2
```

when a new row is to be inserted into this existing table

```
    Value (1,hi,true) #whose combination is already existed in the original table
```

then the count of row onw should be added 1, result in the following table

```
    col1  col2  col3  count
    1     hi    true  2 
    2     ok    true  2 
    3     no    false 2
```

How can this be realised elegantly in PostgreSQL?

Comment: It sounds like you aren't asking how to insert a row, but how to update a value in a row whose fields match certain values.

Comment: Why do you need to store that? You can always retrieve that information using a simple `select` statement. It is usually not a good idea to store data that can be derived from other data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to add unique constraint for `(col1, col2, col3)` first.

```
create index myTable_uk01 on myTable(col1, col2, col3);
```

Now, your table will not allow duplicated rows, which means that the values of `col1`, `col2`, `col3` are all the same.

Then you try `insert` first. If the `insert` succeed, it's ok. If the `insert` failed, then you should issue an `update` command like this:

```
update myTable
set count = count + 1
where col1 = :col1 and col2 = :col2 and col3 = :col3;
```

where `:col1`, `:col2`, `col3` are the values from the record you tried to `insert`.

Comment: I am almost there, but how can I express the semantics of " If the insert succeed, it's ok. If the insert failed, then you should issue an update command like this:"? I have tried python "try..exception.." structure, but that is bad solution. It gives me "current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block".

Answer (score 0):

The best solution may be to add an `insert trigger` onto the table.

So you'd compare then values the `inserted` table against the values that are already in the actual table. If there's a match then just do a simple `update` statement to increment the count.

Here is a linq to explain [triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: Did you see the `postgresql` tag?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I did but I also noticed this line: "problem related to postgresql database, or any database software"